# Limit on number of properties that can be added to Spring Boot Environment

Tags: java, spring-boot

How many properties can be added to Spring Environment? Is the limit combined for properties file and config server? Is there any performance issue before that limit is reached?

Comment: why do you assume there is such a limit?

Comment: I don't know the exact number but I am sure that the bigger issue is the maintainability. So probably you can add hundreds of properties but how will you maintain / document them?